# How to solve these Google Search Console issues?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I'm new using Google Search Console. I see this issue in my console but couldn't find what is the problem? Can anyone help me solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you see the 2nd part of the report, it is clearly saying that the page which was checked by google return 5xx error. Click on Error text and it will navigate to a new page and what error is found will be shown.[image: example here]

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error means your server experienced an error retrieving the content.

Google Search Console has a 'url inspection' tool which will give you more info.

If the above fails you look up your server logs and it will tell you the exact 500 error that's occurring.